# How to pass HTTP status code from service to controller in quarkus?

Tags: api, rest, http-status-codes, quarkus

I am trying to connect to a third-party API from quarkus controller . I have a controller using the method of service.

Controller

```
package com.ncr.invoice;

// all imports over here 

@Path("/api")
@RequestScoped
public class InvoiceController {
    // all variable and injection 
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/invoice")
    @Timeout(250)
    @PermitAll
    public Response getInvoice(AuthTokenRequestModel atrm){
            SoupResponseInvoiceDetail srid = null;
            try{
                 srid = service.getInvoice(
                    atrm.getMcn(),"transactionId", atrm.getInvoiceNumber()
                 );
                 LOG.info("try block end");
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                LOG.info("Over here");
                return Response.status(401).build();
            }
          
            return Response.ok(srid).build();
        }

        return Response.status(401).build();
    }

 
    // all getter setter 
}
```

service

```
@Path("/")
@RegisterRestClient(configKey="invoice-api")
public interface InvoiceService {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/")
    public SoupResponseInvoiceDetail getInvoice(@QueryParam("id") String id,@QueryParam("txn_id") String txnId, @QueryParam("invoice") String invoice) throws InterruptedException;

   
}
```

How to return the HTTP status code from service to controller?
I need to look into the response body when http status is 500

Answer (score 2):

You can return a `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` inside your `InvoiceService` Rest Client instead of the `SoupResponseInvoiceDetail` POJO.

It will allow you to access the raw response with the HTTP response status.

You will still be able to access the response body via `response.readEntity(SoupResponseInvoiceDetail.class)` from inside your `InvoiceController`.